# Using LinkTo to show a single object

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, getjson

I am not using EmberData as I am not that comfortable with it. instead, I am getting the model using `$.getJSON`:

```
App.Persons = App.Model.extend({
    id : null,
    name : null,
    email : null
});

App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Persons.findAll();
    }
});

App.Persons.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return $.getJSON("personsjson.php").then(function(response) {
            var s = [];
            $.each(response, function(i, row) {
                return s.pushObject(App.Persons.create(row));
            });

            return s;
        });
    }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('persons', function() {
        this.resource('person', {
            path : '/:person_id'
        });
    });
});
```

I wanted to show email when someone clicks on the name of person using the LinkTo Helper. So I created a Person route like this,

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        return App.Persons.findBy('id', params.person_id);
    }
});
```

But on the url, instead of getting id at the end, I am getting 'Undefined'.

Here's what I am doing HTML side,

```
            {{#each person in content }}
            <tr><td>
             {{#link-to 'person' this}} <p>{{person.name}}</p>{{/link-to}}
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
```

What could be the issue?

If anyone's interested, I am doing this at the backend,

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM persons;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `this` is a reference to `App.PersonsController`, not an `App.Person` model. So to make this work, pass `person` to the `{{#linkTo}}` like:

```
{{#each person in content }}
    <tr><td>
    {{#link-to 'person' person}} <p>{{person.name}}</p>{{/link-to}}
    </td></tr>
{{/each}}
```

---- UPDATE -----

Also try renaming the model to App.Person instead of App.Persons

```
App.Person = App.Model.extend({
    id : null,
    name : null,
    email : null
});

App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Person.findAll();
    }
});

App.Person.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return $.getJSON("personsjson.php").then(function(response) {
            var s = [];
            $.each(response, function(i, row) {
                return s.pushObject(App.Person.create(row));
            });

            return s;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Whenever I click on this I get this, "This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid."

Comment: Moreover, as expected, url should end with a id, but upon hovering it isn't.

Comment: Could be a problem with naming conventions. Typically your model would be named `App.Person` instead of `App.Persons`.

Comment: Persons model shows all Persons. I just want to show one Person.

Comment: Right but I'm saying rename your model. Will edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I got you now but still there's the same issue.

Comment: Dang. OK, not sure what is causing that. Curious what is `App.Model`. Also can you reproduce in a jsbin?

Comment: App.Model just extends Ember.Object.

Comment: OK made a few changes, jsbin is now working. Using github api as a data source, should be easy to switch back to your own. http://jsbin.com/ORAhEBE/3/edit

Comment: What was the issue? Can you explain a bit?